# GridView with variable width items

Tags: android, listadapter, android-adapterview

I need to achieve a behavior like the [last.fm tag cloud](http://www.lastfm.es/music/Amesoeurs/+tags) on Android.

This means: my items have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, and I need to display horizontally until an item doesn't fit horizontally on the `View`, which will be the first item of the next row. I'd also like to populate the view with a `ListAdapter`.

Writing such View seems overly complicated. Is there any library project that achieves this effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `FlowLayout`. It doesn't exist natively in Android, but Romain Guy (a former Android engineer) gave [a talk showing a quick implementation](http://www.parleys.com/play/2191), and there are also several libraries available that you could use, or easily spin your own.

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout
https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout
http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/
http://hzqtc.github.io/2013/12/android-custom-layout-flowlayout.html