# Make a GridView (Android) With variable Columns By Row, like a UICollectionView

Tags: android, gridview

i'm an iOS developer and i've done this in iOS

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to make this with GridView in Android, but i couldn't. This is because the principle of UICollectionView is Linear like this picture

[image]

Is there some way to do this on Android, or is it better to change my layout?

Comment: gridview is also linear, creating elements from left to right

Comment: But, how can i make cells with variable width ?

Comment: oh variable width is not possible without some sort of custom implementation or library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342518/gridview-with-variable-width-items

Answer (score 1):

You can find a tutorial on Flowlayout [here](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/2191).

Also there are many lib you can find in [this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342518/gridview-with-variable-width-items) (If you dont want to write all the code yourself).

Comment: most welcome! you can mark the ans as correct. Also it helps to filter out unanswerd questions. :)